# When does a custom activity show up in journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, activities

Do custom activities only show up in journey builder once the config file has been set up at the endpoint?

If I just create the activity in the appcenter, but do not actually give it a URL that has been setup yet, will it show up in the side panel in journey builder? Or to have it just show up does the URL have to be actually be setup?

Answer (score 1):

The custom activity will only show up if it is completely configured and hosted at the defined endpoint.